# Non-negative matrix factorization with Euclid's algorithm

Tags: matrices, euclidean-algorithm, linear-groups

I am looking for a proof of this:
Let  $A_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ e $B_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

A matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$, $a+b>c+d$ and $ad-bc=1$ can be factorized as follows:

if $n$ is even and $a>b$: $M=A_{1}^{q_{n}}B_{1}^{q_{n-1}}\dots A_{1}^{q_{2}}B_{1}^{q_{1}}$

if $n$ is odd and $a>b$: $M=\Omega B_{1}^{q_{n}}A_{1}^{q_{n-1}}\dots A_{1}^{q_{2}}B_{1}^{q_{1}}$

if $n$ is even and $a<b$: $M=\Omega B_{1}^{q_{n}}A_{1}^{q_{n-1}}\dots B_{1}^{q_{2}}A_{1}^{q_{1}}$

If $n$ is odd $a<b$: $M=A_{1}^{q_{n}}B_{1}^{q_{n-1}}\dots B_{1}^{q_{2}}A_{1}^{q_{1}}$

where $\Omega=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $q_{1}\dots q_{n}$ are the quotients that appear when Euclid's algorithm is applied to $(a,b)$.

I did myself an induction proof, but I'd like to see it in a book or something, if anyone knows where to look for.

Comment: Alf van der Poorten was very fond of the matrix approach to continued fractions, you may be able to find some paper where he does an exposition – sorry I don't have any references handy. https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/vdp3.pdf might be a good place to start. Or the book, Neverending Fractions: An Introduction to Continued Fractions, by Jonathan Borwein, Alf van der Poorten, Jeffrey Shallit, and Wadim Zudilin.

Comment: Any follow-up, Roger?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: I didn't find anything really useful

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://web.archive.org/web/20150331161808/http://maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/www-centre/alfpapers/a075.pdf

Comment: So, have you had a look at that link, Roger?

Comment: Earth to Roger, come in please.